# Error in Egit in Eclipse: Failure updating tracking ref refs/remotes/origin/5100_<Project_Name>: Missing unknown <commit_id>

Tags: java, git, github

When I'm doing the "pull", I get the below error  message:

```
Failure updating tracking ref refs/remotes/origin/5100_<Project_Name>: 
  Missing unknown <commit_id>
```

- Checked network connection settings in Eclipse - it's fine. I did not
  change my password recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this JGit thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/847612/):

> I think we lack support for [`git pull --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---no-recurse-submodulesyeson-demandno)

Check if the missing unknown commit id is one of a submodule.
That was requested in [issue 488681](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488681) and resolved in [issue 470318](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470318) with [commit 06835f3](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=06835f3e4f0053bb4b39baa02ba4ec32abf3085e) for [JGit 4.9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/New_and_Noteworthy/4.9)

So double-check what version of JGit you have in your Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, the missing commit ID is from submodule. I had older version of JGit4.1 earlier. Now I updated it to JGit 4.11. But still the issue persists.

Comment: @meshsf Can you check if the issue persists when cloning the remote repo in a new eclipse project?

Comment: Yes, after cloning into new eclipse project issue resolved. Later on I downgraded again to older version of JGit4.1 just to cross verify, the error has gone. But I really do not know what was wrong initially with JGit4.1? Thanks for your help.